# Flexbox - firefox layout wrong

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why do the span/images overflow the flex container in firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/ua5ssdp5/

```
article{
    width: 60%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
aside{
    width: 30%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
span{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, FF requires adding `width:100%` to the images

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzds371m/)

Tested in FF40.0.3